# how do i open a .mrstd file format?

Tags: encryption, format

I am trying to open a file used by a reading application on my Kindle HD, and I am trying to export the ton of highlights that i have within the app.

When opening the .mrstd file with sublime text it looks like :

"504b 0304 1400 0808 0800 a46a 8e45 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1d00 0000 636f
6d2e 666c 7965 7273 6f66 742e 6d6f 6f6e
7265 6164 6572 2f6c 6962 2f03 0050 4b07
0800 0000 0002 0000 0000 0000 0050 4b03" and on and on.

what is this & how do i crack it?

please, 
thank you,

nicoara

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** it's a zip file.

In linux, you can use the command "file" which will try to identify the file format.
I asked the same question you did, so I ran `file a.mrstd` and got `a.mrstd: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract`

If you have windows instead,  you can run linux commands using WSL, google for it.